# Jack Audio suppress output with every connection

Tags: terminal, audio, jack

I am running jack on arch linux. Whenever any application on my system connects to jack it dumps out a bunch of information like this:

```
Jack: jack_client_close
Jack: JackClient::Close ref = 8
Jack: JackClient::Deactivate
Jack: JackSocketClientChannel::Stop
Jack: JackPosixThread::Kill
Jack: JackClientSocket::Close
Jack: JackClientSocket::Close
Jack: JackPosixSemaphore::Disconnect name = jack_sem.1000_default_lsp
Jack: JackLibClient::~JackLibClient
Jack: JackShmReadWritePtr1::~JackShmReadWritePtr1 7
Jack: Succeeded in unlocking 422 byte memory area
Jack: JackLibGlobals Destroy 1a64340
Jack: ~JackLibGlobals
Jack: JackPosixSemaphore::Disconnect name = jack_sem.1000_default_system
Jack: JackPosixSemaphore::Disconnect name = jack_sem.1000_default_freewheel
Jack: JackPosixSemaphore::Disconnect name = jack_sem.1000_default_dbusapi
Jack: JackPosixSemaphore::Disconnect name = jack_sem.1000_default_Non-Mixer (input)
Jack: JackPosixSemaphore::Disconnect name = jack_sem.1000_default_qjackctl
Jack: JackPosixSemaphore::Disconnect name = jack_sem.1000_default_Non-Mixer_Master
Jack: JackPosixSemaphore::Disconnect name = jack_sem.1000_default_Non-Mixer (output)
Jack: JackPosixSemaphore::Disconnect name = jack_sem.1000_default_catia
Jack: no message buffer overruns
Jack: JackPosixThread::Stop
Jack: JackPosixThread::ThreadHandler : exit
Jack: JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr 1
Jack: Succeeded in unlocking 1186 byte memory area
Jack: JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr 0
Jack: Succeeded in unlocking 82274202 byte memory area
Jack: jack_client_close res = 0
```

for example if I use `jack_lsp` it will print out the port names correctly followed by the above information. The same thing happens if I connect use `mplayer -ao jack test.mp3`. Is there any way to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Add option to jackd '--silent'

[jackaudio wiki - jackd](https://github.com/jackaudio/jackaudio.github.com/wiki/jackd(1))